# Error: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Failed host lookup: not being caught

Tags: flutter, dio

I am using dio 4.0.2. The problem is that when there is no internet connection(when internet and wifi is not turned on), `SocketException: Failed host lookup` is not being caught. I checked via interceptor's onError method and I am sure it is sending error from interceptor. But post request is not throwing error for this.

Here is my interceptor on error code:

```
@override
 void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
    super.onError(err, handler);
 }
```

How can I catch this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but this worked for me:

```
  // add error interceptor to catch all errors
    dioBuilder.dio.interceptors.add(
      InterceptorsWrapper(
        onError: (error, handler) {
          // Do stuff here
          handler.reject(error); // Added this line to let error propagate outside the interceptor
        },
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it like this:

```
bool _isServerDown(DioError error) {
  return (error.error is SocketException) || (error.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout);
  }


 @override
  Future<void> onError(DioError error, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (_isServerDown(error)) {
      Response? response;
      try {
        response = await tryAnotherUrl(error.requestOptions);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error is DioError) {
          response = error.response;
          handler.next(error);
          return;
        }
      }
      if (response != null) {
        handler.resolve(response);
      } else {
        handler.next(error);
      }
      return;
    }
```